# Windows Phone 7 Add-In for VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have Vs2010 pro from Dreamspark.com and I want to add in the SDK for WP7 
My problem is that I don't find any useful tutorial or thread how to do so.

I know if I download the SDK the VS2010 express and a couple of other things get downloaded as well no prob; but I still want to work in my pro edition. So dose anybody know how to or if there is a way to add-in/plug-in the wp7 Sdk

Thank you in anticipation!

And pls excuse my english I'm not native :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the SDK this will add the WP7 tools & templates for use within Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Express willl still be installed along with everything else you need but shortcuts to it will not be created.

You will still be able to develop in VS2010 pro without any changes to your workflow.

Comment: Dont know when i start the Express editon i can choos windows phone applications/windows phone databound Application/ projects if i start the prof editon the only thing witch has todo with wp7 is the Game application Project and Silvelight projects are new but no specific windows phone application project like the one at the express

Comment: If the options for "XNA Game Studio 4.0" have installed but not the ones for "Silverlight for Windows Phone" it sounds like an incomplete install. Try removing and then reinstalling the phone SDK.

Comment: could it be that the language pack is not compatible i use vs2010 with german lang pack

Comment: so never mind i i did deinstall and install again and didnt work dont know what else to do. funny thing is if i create a new wp7 app in the express edition; i can open it and work it without ANY problems so i guess i will work like this thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a German vs 2010 try to install the German version of the Phone 7 SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displayLang=de